# Should a repository throw custom exceptions or return a status type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository-design

I have web app and a repository that sets a transaction record to 'done'. The requirement is to check at repository level if the requirement has been set already to 'done' by another user, when so, inform the current user that the records has already been set to 'done'.

Should I throw a custom exception or return a status class (with status enum and message collection) ?

The caller of the repository (kind a service) handles the repository calls and wraps the results to a DTO to the UI...

Comment: You should log the exception and return the status class.

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore IMO there is no need to log this because it's not a real exception, it's just like you want to clean your room someone has already done your work for you.

Comment: @WiiMaxx I get it that this isn't an exception, It's actually the expected behavior. But in general, shouldn't a repository just report if a certain transaction was either completed successfully or it did not. If the user is interested in knowing what went wrong, He should be able to see that in the log files.

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore sure but if it's an expected behavior there went nothing wrong right? so in my opinion it's not really worthy to log. In the end it's just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throwing an exception and catching it is not a better practise, because whenever exception occurs, before it's handled, it adds some additional work for the .Net framework to collect all the information like Stacktrace, source and lot of other information.,

Instead have a response RepositoryResponse class as shown below and you can fill in the details and return it to handle in a different layer.

```
class RepositoryResponse
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }

    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, the best option was to return a specific class with status enum and extra info.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply return a [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/sbbt4032.aspx) because why should you throw an exception?
There is no error appeared so there is no need for throw an exception IMHO

here a example of how it cloud look like:

```
public myenum RepositoryMethod()
{
   if(alreadyDone())
     return myenum.AlreadyDone;

   try
   {
       return myenum.Done;
   }
   catch(ex)
   {
       return myenum.ERROR;
   }
}
```